# Are the Timers Event's delegates invoked as thread safe processes?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, thread-safety

I Have 2 **Timers** ([System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) running, both timers Elapsed-Events have delegates subscribed. Both methods(in the subscribed delegates) are working on same objects(lists and objects inside the lists for example).

Say the timers Elapsed-Events were invoked **at the same time**.

Will the delegates run in different threads? Or they will be called one after another?
Should I make the code thread safe, and work with locks?

Comment: Which `Timer` class are you talking about?

Comment: The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) says: *"If the SynchronizingObject property is null, the Elapsed event is raised on a ThreadPool thread. If processing of the Elapsed event lasts longer than Interval, the event might be raised again on another ThreadPool thread. In this situation, the event handler should be reentrant."*  Not exactly describing your situation, but a pretty good clue that the events are not queued up in the same thread.

Comment: meant to: [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

I assume you refer to [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and not [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx). As the documentation says:

*The server-based Timer is designed for use with worker threads in a multithreaded environment. Server timers can move among threads to handle the raised Elapsed event, resulting in more accuracy than Windows timers in raising the event on time.*

There's nothing that guarantees you that two different threads won't raise the `Elapsed` event for two different timers. It's better to make your code thread-safe.

I'm adding a short code snippet to show that multiple callbacks of `Elapsed` can be called at the same time (in this case, causing a deadlock -- `Debug.WriteLine` is never called).

```
var _lock = new object();
GC.KeepAlive(_lock);
var timer1 = new Timer(100);
var timer2 = new Timer(200);
timer1.Elapsed += delegate
{
    lock (_lock)
        Thread.Sleep(-1);
};
timer2.Elapsed += delegate
{
    lock (_lock)
        Debug.WriteLine("Hello world.");
};
timer1.Start();
timer2.Start();
```

Answer (score 1):

They will be queued as workitems in the ThreadPool so, yes, there is a risk that they will execute concurrently. One means of ensuring that this doesn't happen is by only scheduling a single timer callback and the recurrent time to [infinte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timeout.infinite.aspx) (`System.Threading.Timer` supports this), and rescheduling when the work is complete.

Answer (score 1):

Timer callbacks (you don't specify the specific class/namespace) are always called in a separate thread.  So you should make your code thread safe.
Whether they will be called 'at the same time' or subsequently off course depends on their interval set.
With a same interval set, which callback will be called first is pretty much non-deterministic.